# Mittag-Lefflers's Theorem - The meaning of "having no interior accumulation point"

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading the book Function Theory of One Complex Variable, third edition (Robert E. Greene and Steven G. Krantz). In the section of Mittag-Leffler's theorem (section 8.3) he always use (theorems 8.3.1, 8.3.6 and 8.3.7) a sequence that has no accumulation point in the open set $U$. In theorem 8.3.8 they use the following expression: *... be a finite or countably infinite set os distinct points of $U$ having no interior accumulation point*.

What does it means? I'm not sure if it means the same that they stated in the other theorems. I was wondering if it means that there is no point of the sequence that is an accumulation point of the sequence (because of the word 'interior'). Any sugestion?

Comment: It think it means that any accumulation points of the sequence must lie on the boundary of $U$, not in its interior.

Comment: But since $U$ is open it's equivalent to say 'with no accumulation point in $U$' (as they said in others theorems). Perhaps they just change the way of writing, but I think that it's confusing.

Comment: Perhaps the result holds regardless of whether or not $U$ is open. At any rate, the author is probably just trying to use the openness only where it is actually needed. I'm only guessing at the intent here.

Comment: They take an open set $U$ in the beginning of the theorem, so I think that it's not the case. But thank you!

Comment: This simply means that a possible maybe accumulation point of your set is not interior, i. e. is not contained in an open contained in $U$; for example the sequence {$\frac{1}{n}$} in the open interval $(0,1)$ in which $0$ is an accumulation point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ataulfo. As I've said above, the set $U$ is always fixed as a open set. So, it's equivalent to say that a point is an interior point of $U$ or that a point is a poinf of $U$. I had this doubt because he always used the expression 'which has no accumulation point in $U$', except in this theorem, where he used the expression 'having no interior accumulation point'. Maybe it's just another way to write, but I found these change too strange. Thanks again.

Comment: In the usual [french definition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_d'accumulation_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29), an accumulation point of a subset $A$ in a topological space $E$ need not be in $A$. That's the equivalent of [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) in english I believe. Is there another english definition for *accumulation point*?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, when $U$ is open, the expressions

- a set in $U$ having no accumulation point in   $U$.
- a set in $U$ having no interior accumulation point.

say the same thing.  The book author may be using one and then the other because when writing one page, they consulted book A, and when writing another page, they looked at book B, and were influenced by the style adopted there.

Comment: In the condition *no accumulation point **in $U$***, the last two words are important.

Comment: Yes, I changed my comment. Anyway, I think the OP didn't pay enough attention to this. Being in U is equivalent to being interior, when U is open. This has nothing to do with accumulation points.